# Issue with MySQL functions in HeidiSQL

Tags: mysql, heidisql

Now I create a mySQL function in HeidiSQL for the first time, and it keeps giving me the following error:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near " at line 5

I can't understand, my function is pretty simple. Besides, I copied the function syntax from the MySQL Reference Manual. And here is the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufn_get_salary_level(salary DECIMAL(19,4))

RETURNS VARCHAR(10)

BEGIN

   DECLARE salary_level VARCHAR(10);

   IF salary < 30000 THEN SET salary_level = 'Low';

   ELSEIF salary >= 30000 AND salary <= 50000 THEN SET salary_level = 'Average';

   ELSEIF salary > 50000 THEN SET salary_level = 'High';

   END IF;

   RETURN salary_level;

END;
```

when I use DELIMITER, it keeps giving me another error message:

> SQL Error (1418): The function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled...

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION ufn_get_salary_level(salary DECIMAL(19,4))

RETURNS VARCHAR(10)

DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
   DECLARE salary_level VARCHAR(10);

   IF salary < 30000 THEN SET salary_level = 'Low';

   ELSEIF salary >= 30000 AND salary <= 50000 THEN SET salary_level = 'Average';

   ELSEIF salary > 50000 THEN SET salary_level = 'High';

   END IF;

   RETURN salary_level;

END $$

DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Geuss you are going to need to use DELIMITER. because i can't see anny other syntax errors.

Comment: Update the question with new information don't post it in comments..

Comment: Yes, I updated - do you see any error in the version with DELIMITER?

Comment: The function works here: http://rextester.com/MACK99070

Comment: Then what can be the reason for such errors?

Comment: Well the first error is not very helpfull. But the second can probably be fixed if you add `DETERMINISTIC` before `BEGIN`.

Comment: After adding DETERMINISTIC before BEGIN, I get the following error: SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1. No idea...